# In Metal Gear Solid V, do forward operating base get invaded offline?

Tags: ps4, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm on mission 30 and I have a question about forward operating bases. I want to concentrate on the primary missions first, but it is almost mandatory to create a FOB, when I go online. My question is, Can I create a forward operating base and play offline without getting invaded? I don't want to pay attention to that for a while.

Comment: [Are FOBs necessary to complete the game?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/236672/33618)

Comment: [How to secure your FOB?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/237327/33618)

Answer (score 5):

**No you can not, unfortunately.**

It has been confirmed on numerous occasions that you can get invaded even though you are not online.

[Source](http://www.konami.jp/mgs5/tpp/faq/item.php5?id=67&region=ac&lang=en).

Comment: This is awfull. :( I want to play the whole game without being forced to play in FOB.

Comment: I've not played as far as you, but as I understand it you don't have to create a FOB. So, don't missunderstand me, you can play through the entire game without playing in FOB. As long as you don't "start it".

Comment: that's the thing, it's impossible at this point. The game force you to create a FOB. There's no way of going back to the game without creating one, I pause the game for that reason. Maybe I just try to disconnect the wi-fi from the ps4.

Comment: Hopefully you can still pick up the daily rewards when you're past the "create a FOB" part.

Comment: If it has been confirmed on numerous occasions, could you provide sources of reference?

Comment: Updated with source.

Comment: You need a FOB to do some things in the game, but you shouldn't worry about being invaded and having all your stuff stolen. I've been actively participating in FOB and have revealed my base to a number of rivals now. After a couple days so far, all my rivals have taken 29 soldiers (only 1 A+, and 2 A) and 650 Resources. This can be recovered by the player after 1 mission or a couple quick side ops. It's not as bad as you might think to get attacked/infiltrated.

Comment: That, and you are immune to infiltrations after you get infiltrated for up to 24 hours depending on how badly they ruined your assets. [Source](http://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/metal-gear-solid-v-fob-guide-tips-for-online-invasions/)

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Oh, that's good. Anyway, I just finish the whole game alredy, now I'm planning on create the FOB. How did I manage to get that far without creating a FOB? well, easy, I disconnected the internet from the ps4.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy Insurance for your FOB with MB coins, and the first time you do this it is free.  0 MB coins for your first insurance. I believe its so you have time to develop your FOB to a decent defensible state and learn the mechanics.