# Are FOBs necessary to complete the game?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

As I understand it, if you create a Forward Operating Base ([FOB](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Forward_operating_base)) you open yourself to being raided by other players of the game.

I do not plan on raiding other players and quiet frankly would rather just not have the hassle: I do not have much time to play games and would rather not have my hard earned soldiers and resources stolen.

Is it possible to finish all the main ops (except the FOB tutorial op 22?) without constructing a [FOB](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Forward_operating_base)?

Comment: According to the release notes currently shown upon starting the game (on PS4, in my case), your FOB cannot be raided if you're playing in offline mode (by selecting disconnect from the pause menu). Can anyone confirm if this is correct? I've heard reports of FOBs being raided while the game is offline, or the game isn't even running, but that may have been changed within the last two weeks.

Comment: I'll have to write down the exact wording of the notification when I start up the game tonight, and post a question citing it.

Comment: FOB is an online mode. As Metal Gear Solid does not **require** online, we can infer that it is not vital to the main story line.

Comment: @Sardathrion I posted a detailed question about whether it's possible to avoid attacks by keeping the game offline: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236747/can-other-players-attack-your-fob-while-youre-offline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can complete all missions without needing to touch FOBs (except for the mandatory tutorial you mentioned).

But having to go through this does open you up for invasions by other players, and unfortunately there is nothing that can be done about this as you can still be invaded whilst offline.

There is a 'cooldown' period between invasions so you won't be constantly bombarded by enemies.

I'm personally not planning on using FOBs myself in my playthrough - I've been playing since launch and have only been invaded once so far.

Comment: I am not sure that the advantages of having FOBs are worth the hassle of getting raided despite the (short) cool down. I play a few hours a week, I would hate to come back to find I have nothing left of my resources/soldiers since I was raided every day since the last time I played. I do not have time for getting it all back via grind.

Comment: @Sardathrion I think I'm in the same position as you - I'm not using FOBs because of my time limitations. I'd prefer to have been able to skip it entirely to avoid the hassle. But so far, I've been able to ignore it and it hasn't really had any impact on my gameplay experience. I've heard differing accounts, but from what I can gather, is that only the resources gained from the FOB can be stolen from your FOB, so your main motherbase resources should be safe.