# FOB creation episode(s)

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Since you can [finish the game without FOBs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/236672/33618) and I do not want to create any FOB so I do not have to play on line<sup>1</sup>. As I understand it, during ep 21, you get a call to defend Mother Base thus starting ep. 22.

**Is it just ep. 22 or do I have to avoid ep. 21 as well?**

Can you just safely ignore the call to return to base?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>I have a very limited time I can spend playing the game. Spending an hour a week grinding to get stolen resources back is not my idea of fun as his is about a third of the time I can play games. Thus, I want to *avoid getting in the situation that I can be raided*.</sup></sub>

Comment: You can avoid playing online by simply selecting "DISCONNECT" from the pause menu. No mission-dodging necessary. Alternatively, just unplug your Ethernet cable or disable your wi-fi and start up the game.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc:  This does not work as far as I know. You can still be raided if you are off line, you just hear about it when you are back on line.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about that part. Whoops. Actually, though, if you play the entire game off-line, I don't see how they could raid you -- how would their servers know that you ever built an FOB to begin with? Might be something worth trying, but it would require starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To advance in the story line, you will need to do these missions and it is mandatory to create a FOB as part of the tutorial.

Unfortunately, the statement "you can finish the game without FOBs" doesn't mean that you can go through the game without building one, it means that you can go through the game without playing that mode after passing the tutorial (at which point you will have a FOB set up).

If you have an internet connection, it will force you to do the FOB tutorial, which will create your FOB and open it up for attack. If you can avoid connecting to the internet while playing you can skip it. Afaik, as soon as you reconnect to the internet, it will take you through the FOB tutorial. So if you want to avoid FOBs, disconnect from the internet before mission 22 and don't reconnect at all.

Comment: As I understand it, if you have constructed a FOB then it can be raided by any other player. This is what I am trying to avoid. From my other question, it seem to be possible. From what you say here, it seems that I have to suck it and get all my stuff stolen.

Comment: If you have an internet connection, it will force you to do the FOB tutorial, which will create your FOB and open it up for attack. If you can avoid connecting to the internet while playing you can skip it. Afaik, as soon as you reconnect to the internet, it will take you through the FOB tutorial. So if you want to avoid FOBs, disconnect from the internet before mission 22 and don't reconnect at all.

Comment: Well, that sucks. I use the PS4 for other things and those require network.  Plugin/Unplugin it all is a PITA and there's almost no chance that I will always remember to unplug it.  *sigh*

Comment: (Comment added to answer). Same with me. I can't be bothered to unplug before each time I play, so I've just gone through the FOB tutorial and keeping my fingers crossed that I don't get too badly raided..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to build a FOB to complete mission 22.

As long as you remain offline, you shouldn't get a prompt to build one, and may continue back with mission 21 at your leisure.