# Can I opt out of the MGSV multiplayer base invasions?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am somewhat interested in playing MGSV, but when playing a singleplayer game, I really hate it when my efforts are undermined by forced competitive multiplayer like base invasions, especially if people are cheating their way to victory.

It does not matter how big or small the loss is, the hate is primarily psychological. My opinion is: I worked for it, I spent time to unlock it and/or gather it. If another player, while playing the same game I do, can take something I earned in a singleplayer game away from me, that just breaks my morale, especially if it happens multiple times.

Is there a way to opt out completely from the competitive multiplayer components of MGSV so other people can not detract from the efforts I made? I don't mind any multiplayer that is beneficial or neutral, like auction houses or PvE.

I am open to any solutions.

---

My question is different from [Are FOBs necessary to complete the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236672/are-fobs-necessary-to-complete-the-game) in that while I do not want the invasions, I do want to make full use of the FOB. The duplicate question asks "can I ignore FOBs?" while I ask "Can I use FOBs without risking invasions?".

Comment: I believe they recently added this feature, but I'm not in front of my game right now so I'm not 100% certain. I'd like to add that in nearly 100 hours of playing I've never once been invaded.

Comment: There are at least two factions of players who will invade people with nukes sooner or later to steal them. Once you are advanced enough. you're a target.

Comment: True, but nukes are completely optional to build and are never required. They're used to put you on a different invasion list, and little else.

Comment: +1: I haven't played MGS5 yet, but I've been curious about this since I heard that single-player bases could be invaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are FOBs necessary to complete the game?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236672/are-fobs-necessary-to-complete-the-game)

Comment: @LoboDemon It's not a duplicate, as I explained in my edit. I don't mind using the FOB and I want to use it. I do mind that people can undermine the efforts I made. I hated it when the CPU opponent did it in AC:Revelations, I hate it in Grepolis, I hate it in Hobbit: KoME. I will probably hate it in MGSV as well.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Fair enough, makes sense.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: If you hated AC:R's defense mechanics, then opting out of FOB invasions isn't going to satisfy you. Losing what you've worked for is a huge theme of TPP. Even if you go offline, you're going to get sucker-punched by several major plot points and single-player game mechanics. You may want to give serious consideration to playing a different game.

Comment: @user2357112 I can handle it if it's part of the plot. AC:R was just a mechanic that lead into a horribly designed minigame. What singleplayer game mechanics that aren't plot points will cause me to lose what I've worked for?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: The ones with the big impact are the direct mechanical effect of big, spoilery plot points, so I'm hiding them behind [this link](http://pastebin.com/2YqgcUZY). You'll also lose a ton of people to Combat Deployments if you choose to do them, since no matter how good your squad composition, you can't eliminate the chance of casualties. You probably won't feel it, though.

Comment: @user2357112 In WoW, I deal with such losses all the times through the shipyard. Any mission that's not at 100% chance of success can cost you one or more of your ships. You cannot eliminate the chance of casualties, but can you eliminate the chance of failure? Either way, I'll probably wait until next year to buy it, so people  are busy playing Fallout 4, Syndicate, GTA V, Just Cause 3 or any of the other open world games on PC. It will be cheaper by then, and fewer people will be playing and invading my base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

**It is not possible to use FOBs without risking invasions. Neither is it possible to not construct a FOB.**<sup>2</sup>

There is **no way** to opt out of FOB construction as it is needed to advance the single player plot. Therefore there is **no way** to stop others from raiding your FOB. Being off line does not work: your FOBs can still be raided while you are offline.

## It is nothing to worry about

*However, just like I was, you are worrying for nothing.*

I shared your **exact** same concerns and since FOBs are *mandatory*, I asked [how to secure your FOB](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237327/how-to-secure-your-fob).  I followed the [advice given](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/237338/33618) have had a FOB for several weeks now and never been invaded once.  It could be a statistical blip, I might be raided as you are read this. However, my FOB is a useless piece of junk that is super defended by losers (C-rank or below) on high alert and hight technology gear.

However, even if you are raided and lose fully: **It still does not matter**. FOB offer you two major advantages: two more units to dispatch on missions and a huge increase in staff numbers. Those alone will offset any lose you make when being invaded.

Your FOB will be bury in a long long list of FOBs. If you invade other FOBs, then they get to know you as an enemy.  Thus, they are more likely to take revenge on you<sup>1</sup>. If you do not invade them, your FOB looks like a piece of trash that will be really expensive to invade: why bother? Think of it as your FOB increasing your productivity by 100% but sometimes (very rarely) you will lose 1% of that.  Net result: You have 99% increase in productivity.  Still a win.

You *could* build a nuke.  This would stop anyone without high enough heroism from invading you, turn you into [Demon Snake](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72444559), and turn you into a target for those with high heroism to steal your nuke to either sell it on or disarm it. I would not chose that path…

## A yearly update

It has been longer than a year, since I wrote this answer, I now have two FOBs build, and have had **not one invasion**. However, I am raking in the benefits from being able to send two extra team of the S+ soldiers to harvest resources.

---

<sup><sub>**1**: Almost of this was a theme of the game, or something. ☺</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>**2**: Actually, that's not true. Just do not progress past Mission 20. However, that cuts out about 30 missions and lots of side ops from the game.</sub></sup>

Comment: I do not want to opt out of construction. I fully want to construct one, but I do not want to be a target for invasions, which to me are just tacked on multiplayer shenanigans which start to get into extortion racket territories with the insurance Konami sells.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: You cannot opt out of constructing a FOB.  Which means that you are left open to be raided. However, you can mitigate the risks of being raided. Answer edited.

Answer (score 4):

**These invasions aren't really bothersome.**

At low levels, you aren't worth invading because you definitely don't have anything worth stealing, and the volunteers gained from invading you will also suck. Most people invade FOBs so that they can get S-rank and higher recruits, which will join them as volunteers once they invade someone with advanced-enough security. The other reason you would be invaded is that you possess a nuclear weapon, which is completely optional and doesn't even get unlocked as an option until close to the end of the game. Players will invade other players that possess nukes so that they can steal and then either sell or dismantle the nuke. Dismantling nuclear weapons gives a lot of Heroism, which is a stat that influences how many volunteers you get and how good they are.

**Not that much evidence of cheating yet.**

I have no experience with cheaters online, but I have seen it done in videos. Cheating is unfortunately a common problem in these Japanese-developed games with fleshed-out multiplayer features -- see *Dark Souls* for another case study. Japanese publishers don't ever seem to prioritize putting a stop to cheating post-release or allowing their devs to put the necessary precautions in place to prevent it. It's just an unfortunate trend that I've observed when I play any Japanese-made game's multiplayer feature. The one exception that I've witnessed is *Monster Hunter*, which would suffer very greatly from cheaters due to its quasi-MMO persistence and grind. Heck, there might be a lot of cheaters in *MH4U* -- I haven't played it at the highest tier, so I can't say for sure.

However, from my experience and discussion with others, it seems that cheating isn't a big problem in this game -- at least, not yet.

**Losing an invasion isn't really something you have to worry about.**

If someone infiltrates your base to its core successfully, you really don't have that much to worry about. You will lose some resources which you will have in large abundance by the end of the game and are farmed automatically in large numbers, and troops that are replaceable because they're not on your Direct Contract list. Direct Contract is a mechanic that allows you to put a limited number of staff on it so that they can't be killed or Fultoned during an infiltration. I find that the game provides ample enough Direct Contract slots so that I don't have to worry about losing the staff I actually care about.

In fact there is actually a question on this site where someone is asking how to make it *easier* for someone to successfully infiltrate his base, because he astutely recognized that defenders get much, *much* less for winning a defense than attackers get for winning an infiltration, and additionally defenders really don't lose much of value when the infiltration is successful.

From my overall view, it seems like Konami/KojiPro intended for FOBs to be a sort of "Farmville" mechanic in the game, where you can build up your bases with cool security features, up your ranking in the Virtual League, and increase your resource gain. The infiltrations seem like they were designed to be rewarding for attackers (who are just looking for extra challenging gameplay) while being minimally damaging to the defender, so they don't have to worry about being attacked. This encourages people to go out and invade FOBs frequently. The FOBs were built as a sort of additional sub-game on top of MGSV -- the features lend it towards having little impact on your actual game unless you *want* it to.

Comment: This answer is accurate. Don't even worry about it. I only constructed what I had to make for an FOB. Logged a good 16-20 hours in since and haven't been invaded once. It's simply not worth the risk for them if you don't upgrade anything. And you don't lose out on a ton by not upgrading stuff.

Comment: FOBs are designed to supplement your normal base in terms of resource generation and staff housing, so I highly recommend you upgrade them. That being said, you don't really have to worry about the invasion mechanic at all. With the online dispatch missions, it's trivial to replace even A++ staff members, and anyone higher should be under direct contract.

Comment: I can get that it might not be a big deal and that you can negate it by not buying nukes and keeping your upgrades under control, but for me it's mainly the psychological side. If it's an MMO, I only do PvE and if it's not, I exclusively do singleplayer because I really don't like losses that I can't do anything about, even if they're minor. It just seems like really cheap game design that a player can lose anything they worked for (read: have to play more) just because another player is playing their game.

Comment: I feel this goes to a great amount of effort answering why it wont matter, which addresses concerns OP raises, **but does not answer the actual question at all**.

Comment: @Timelord64 Problem solving isn't always a matter of answering the question directly. I am here primarily to serve the asker, not the site's rules. No offense.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I understand and empathize with you a lot -- in fact, normally I would side with you -- but I find it difficult to understate how little of an impact enemy invasions have had on my gameplay. I was never invaded by another player once during my entire playthrough of 140+ hours (there is a tutorial "invasion" that teaches you how FOB infiltration works, so don't panic when that happens). I don't want you to pass up playing the game, which has over 100 hours of good content even though it's unfinished, because you're afraid of losing something that really has no impact on your game.

Comment: We are a Q and A site, so yeah, answering the question OP asks is of top priority. You are now discussing the problem with OP, who this does not appear to have heped. This has since turned into an effective argument over "does it really matter". **OP has since told you that this has not addressed their concerns**. You respond by suggesting that **OP must be wrong on the basis that you had a different experience**. This is not what we are about, at all..

Comment: Also see [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/flagging-answers-that-answer-a-completely-different-question)

Comment: Lucas, your experience has completely no relevance to my experience. It's perfectly possible that your base isn't being attacked for a reason that you're not aware of, and it's perfectly possible that my base could be raided multiple times per week or per day because of another reason that you're also unaware of. I have already said that even if there's very little gameplay impact, my main concern is the psychological impact of having my efforts in a predominantly singleplayer game being affected by other players in an, in my opinion, tacked-on multiplayer side.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but I agree it doesn't really answer the question. It seems this is more about the psychological aspect of being invaded in this asynchronous multiplayer. I'm not sure if we can really address that to a level that with satisfy the asker's (completely legitimate) concerns.

Comment: @twobugs: What the OP is asking for is not possible.  This answer kinda answers it by saying "do not worry, it's not as bad as you think" and as such is only missing a "No" at the start.

Comment: I can't check at work, but as I mentioned in my comment on the question I do recall reading that Konami added a feature like this recently. If I'm not mistaken, it definitely is answerable. I'll check when I get home today (apologies, yesterday I prioritized viewing the Birthday scene, which is glorious).

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Then you should have specified that the principle of the thing matters that much for you in the OP. I am a pragmatist, so I was trying to address your practical concerns by telling you this has no substantial effect on the meat of the game. I do not worry about things that have no effects on my gameplay; sorry for the misunderstanding. Timelord64: I did not say that OP is wrong -- I even went so far as to say **I agree with him**. Why the antagonism?

Answer (score 1):

According to Konami - **Yes.**

Selecting "Online Disconnect" from the pause menu will allow you to play without being invaded by other players.

Here are the official notes:

> TIPS: About Online Disconnect: 
>   If you want to play offline without worrying about coming under attack from rival players, select ONLINE DISCONNECT under the Pause Menu.

It's difficult to find validation or even much discussion about this recently introduced feature, but I have no located a single case of someone being invaded after using it.

Comment: How positively Konami. I'll leave this answer up then in hopes that you're wrong (no offense), but I think you're most likely correct.

Comment: From the Konami web site, dated Tuesday, October 6th, 2015 [Your FOBs are always at risk of coming under attack. Now, you can rest easy with FOB insurance (paid service)](http://www.konami.jp/mgs5/tpp/en/news/day30.php5). Nothing like good conflicting information, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if "Neither is it possible to not construct a FOB.2 2: Actually, that's not true. Just do not progress past Mission 20." was true when written. But it definitely is NOT true now. I've completed mission 29 and have NOT constructed an FOB. I'm not sure if it's because I've always had the game blocked in my firewall so it has never connected to Konami but, nevertheless, I've never constructed one and so far it hasn't prevented me from progressing in the single player storyline well past mission 20. I just wanted to post this in case someone else like me came along later to read this they would be aware of the current state of things and not mistakenly believe they are forced to construct one.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to opt out of building a FOB, I want to opt out of the invasions that accompagny it. The FOB gives a number of other benefits that I'd rather not miss. I understand that it gives a number of bonuses for the main game, and I'm also a big fan of unlocking persistent stuff that I can just check off. I just love having a game within a game where I can play the main game to collect upgrades and items to use in the game within a game.